# Hacker Experience I recently just got added to Safenet's list, is my IP on a text file on their server?

Tags: hacker-experience

I recently got added to Safenet's list after deleting a file for a mission. I know you only stay on the list for and hour, but I also heard there is a .txt file on the Safenet server containing the full IP of everyone on the front page. Is this true?

P.S. I can't do an IP reset for a while so I'm worried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no there is no txt file on safenet showing anyones ip as it has been deleted / cleared

Comment: Thanks, really puts a load off of my chest. I just got a cracker capable of hacking Safenet and there is no text file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a file. Howevor, many people who get on the list hack into Safenet to delete it (or at minimum, erase their IP). If you manage to hack into Safenet and open the file, you will be able to see the full ips of others. Howevor, the file is rarely remains for more than a few minutes before someoene who is told he is on the list deletes it.